# Clear previous activity array when backpressed, android

Tags: android, android-intent

In my android app, i have three activities. The first activity takes the user input and passes the value of a long through Intent extras to second activity, on the basis of which the second activity shows content. Then this second activity takes some user inputs and passes a long array to third activity though Intent , on the basis of which it shows the content. 
Now when i backpress from third activity to second activity, i want the user inputs of second activity to be cleared that were store in long array, but my string value which second activity gets from first activity to be remained as it is. 
Can anyone guide me , how to achieve this.

*EDIT:*
**SECOND_ACTIVITY_CODE:**

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_details);
    //get long from first activity
    Bundle firstactivitybundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        myLong1 = firstactivitybundle.getLong("key");
    //send this long to SQLITE db and get details
    Dbadapter details = new Dbadapter(this);
        details.open();
        data =details.getDetailedSymps(myLong1);
        details.close();
    //Display these details in form of checkboxes
     for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
                cb.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                cb.setButtonDrawable(id);
                cb.setText(data[i]);
                checkboxLayout1.addView(cb);
    //saving checkbox state in an singleton class for later use
                AppData.getInstance().setSensation(data[i]);
         }
    //second activity button
            next1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Next1);
           next1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for (int i = 0; i < checkboxLayout1.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    if (checkboxLayout1.getChildAt(i) instanceof CheckBox) {
                        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) checkboxLayout1.getChildAt(i);
                        if (cb.isChecked()) {
                         senssymp = cb.getText().toString();
//getting Ids of checkboxes that are checked from SQLITE db       
                         Dbadapter senscheck = new Dbadapter(getApplicationContext());
                         senscheck.open();
                         sensdetailId = senscheck.getsensdetailId(senssymp);
                         senscheck.close();
//saving ids in a list
                         sensIdList.add(sensdetailId);
                     }

                    }   
                }
//converting list to long array     
             String[] getSym = sensIdList.toArray(new String[sensIdList.size()]);
              long[] sens_checked_ids = new long[getSym.length];  
                for (int i = 0; i < getSym.length; i++) {  
                  sens_checked_ids[i] = Long.valueOf(getSym[i]);  
                }  
// finally create a bundle and sending the long array containg Ids to 3rd activity
                Bundle bundle_sensIds = new Bundle();
               bundle_sensIds.putLongArray("sens ids", sens_checked_ids);
               Intent final_intent = new Intent(DetailActivity.this,FinalActivity.class);
            final_intent.putExtras(bundle_sensIds);
            startActivity(final_intent);
            }
        });
        }
```

**SOLUTION:**

In onStop() of my second activity , i cleared the sensIdList that was saving all the Ids

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {

    super.onStop();
    sens_checked_ids= new long[sens_checked_ids.length];
    sensIdList.clear();

}
```

and the problem solved.

Comment: Try to make one static flag isClear in Second Activity and try to set value true on back pressed in Third Activity now check this flag in onResume() Second Activity base on value clean you Second Activity data object.

Comment: @HareshChhelana ! Can you explain this with some example please?

Comment: simple check if your long array size `>0` then clear it in `onCreate()` of second activity.

Comment: @Rustam! tried it , but its giving me 'nullPointerException' error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For opening a new instance of activity, you can try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityC.this, ActivityB.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);  //this combination of flags would start a new instance even if the instance of same Activity exists.
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME);
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

And if you don't want that and just need to clear data, then you can try this in `onResume` of activityB:

```
myArray = new String[]; //reinitialize all data structure
myArrayList= new ArrayList<String>();
sens_checked_ids = new long[];
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this just use this code in your onStop method of **second activity**

```
 //get long from first activity
Bundle firstactivitybundle = getIntent().getExtras();
myLong1 = firstactivitybundle.getLong("key",null);
if(myLong1 !=null){
//Do your stuff 
}


@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

     //You can use same code just before calling your third activity 
     getIntent().removeExtra("key");
     //OR May be try like this
     getIntent().setLong("key",null);          
}
```

It's just gives you basic idea to achive your requirmnet because you have not posted any code here.

Comment: tried this, but unable to clear my long array of second activity. When i return from third activity to second activity , the array contains value of previous user-inputs

Comment: why don't you post your second activity code so we can suggest you appropriate answer!!!.

Comment: Why you are calling getIntent() method in second activity? I want my long array to be null, not the long value from the first activity.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

Try to take one static flag (isClear) in Second Activity and try to set value true on back pressed in Third Activity now check this flag in onResume() Second Activity base on value clean you Second Activity data object

**Second Activity**

```
public static boolean isClear;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
   if(isClear){
      isClear=false;
      // try to clear data here
   }
   super.onResume();
}
```

**Third Activity**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   SecondActivity.isClear=true;
   super.onBackPressed();
}
```